# what should be done with these lines in the following arch.make file?

Tags: 12.04, bash, source-packages

I want to install siesta (a computational code) to run parallel in Ubuntu 12.04.
There is an arch.make file which a part of it's content is as follows:

```
    .SUFFIXES:
  .SUFFIXES: .f .F .o .a .f90 .F90

  SIESTA_ARCH=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu--unknown

  FPP=
  FPP_OUTPUT=
  FC=/opt/pool/openmpi/bin/mpif90
  RANLIB=ranlib

  SYS=nag

  SP_KIND=4
  DP_KIND=8
  KINDS=$(SP_KIND) $(DP_KIND)

  FFLAGS=-g -O2
  FPPFLAGS= -DFC_HAVE_FLUSH -DFC_HAVE_ABORT -DGRID_DP -DPHI_GRID_SP -DMPI
  LDFLAGS=

  ARFLAGS_EXTRA=

  FCFLAGS_fixed_f=
  FCFLAGS_free_f90=
  FPPFLAGS_fixed_F=
  FPPFLAGS_free_F90=

  LIBPATH=/opt/pool/scalapack_installer-1.8.0

  BLAS_LIBS=/usr/lib/libf77blas.a /usr/lib/atlas/libblas.a
  LAPACK_LIBS=/usr/lib/atlas/liblapack.a
  BLACS_LIBS= -L$(LIBPATH) -lblacsF77 -lblacsC -lblacs
  SCALAPACK_LIBS=-lscalapack

  COMP_LIBS=

  NETCDF_LIBS=
  NETCDF_INTERFACE=

  LIBS=$(SCALAPACK_LIBS) $(BLACS_LIBS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(NETCDF_LIBS) -lpthread

  #SIESTA needs an F90 interface to MPI
  #This will give you SIESTA's own implementation
  #If your compiler vendor offers an alternative, you may change
  #to it here.
  MPI_INTERFACE=libmpi_f90.a
  MPI_INCLUDE=./include
```

So, according to this. I have some questions, please:

1- what do the following lines mean? (what happens in them?)(for the second line, I don't know what does it mean to write `BLAS_LIBS` and equal to an address.)

```
.SUFFIXES: .f .F .o .a .f90 .F90
BLAS_LIBS=/usr/lib/libf77blas.a /usr/lib/atlas/libblas.a
```

2-what should be written after the equal sign in the following lines?

```
 FPP=
  FPP_OUTPUT=
NETCDF_LIBS=
```

3-should the expressions in the right side of equal sign in the following line be replaced by something? if yes, what should be written?!

```
LIBS=$(SCALAPACK_LIBS) $(BLACS_LIBS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(NETCDF_LIBS)
```

I know some basics of bash scripting and familiar with command line in linux. I have watched several training courses about bash scripting but I'm still perplexed!!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: IMHO this is outside the scope of AskUbuntu. For general information about Makefiles, such as the meaning of `.SUFFIXES`, see [Managing Projects with GNU Make, Third Edition By Robert Mecklenburg](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp). For your other questions, did you read the 'COMPILATION' section of the [Siesta manual](http://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/Documentation/Manuals/manuals.html)? There is a section about the `arch.make` file specifically, and a suggestion for how to generate an appropriate one automatically using the provided `../Src/configure` script. G/L.

Comment: Thanks so much
I used the arch.make for MPI and got the following errors:


f95 -c -g -O2 -I   mpi__include.f90
f95: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mpi__include.o] Error 4

Answer (score 2):

A `.SUFFIXES` rule in a Makefile determines which implicit rules are used during compilation. A detailed explanation would be off-topic here, but you can read all you want to know in Chapter 2 *Rules* in O'Reilly's [Managing Projects with GNU Make, Third Edition By Robert Mecklenburg](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp).

Regarding the assignments of variables such as `FPP`, `FPP_OUTPUT`, `NETCDF_LIBS` you will need to refer to the software's own documentation to determine suitable values for these - we might *guess* based on context that `FPP` stands for a Fortran pre-processor (by analogy with `CPP`) but that's by no means guaranteed.

---

Your underlying question seems to be *"How do I build the siesta computational chemistry software on Ubuntu 12.04?"*. Here's what worked for me (YMMV - depending what pre-existing software is installed on your system):

1. Install the pre-requisites - for me these were a Fortran compiler, plus regular and MPI versions of the BLAS and LAPACK libraries, which I did as

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gfortran libatlas-dev liblapack-dev libscalapack-mpi-dev
   ```
2. Unpack the software and change to the `Obj` directory

   ```
   tar xf siesta-4.1-b1.tar.gz
   cd siesta-4.1-b1/Obj
   ```
3. As indicated in the `Obj/README` file, run the provided script to populate the directory,

   ```
   ../Src/obj_setup.sh
   ```
4. As suggested by the script, run the provided configure script to create a suitable `arch.make` file

   ```
   ../Src/configure
   ```

   **If you're still interested in the answers to your questions (2) and (3) at this point, you can look into the created `arch.make` file to see the automatically configured values**
5. Build the software

   At this point, you should be ready to `make`, however it appears that the configure step doesn't quite take care of everything since it fails with the message

   ```
   SIESTA: dc_lapack.a has been deprecated in favor of:
     COMP_LIBS += libsiestaLAPACK.a
   Please update your arch.make file accordingly...
   ```

   Although you *could* edit the `arch.make` file, IMHO it's simpler for such a small change to pass the variable definition on the `make` command line

   ```
   make "COMP_LIBS += libsiestaLAPACK.a"
   ```
6. If the build completes successfully, you can run the provided tests by changing to the `Obj/Tests` directory and running `make` there

   ```
   cd Tests/
   make
   ```

The tests may take considerably more time than the build.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i think this would not install "parallel" siesta...!!!

Comment: is this installation enough to run the program on a 2 core with 8 cpus?!